# Is there a way to add views bulk operations to a custom table in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I created a custom table from a custom module using theme table; `theme('table', array('header' => $table_header, 'rows' => $data));` the data that I'm showing can not be retrieved from views as i'm showing data from a 3rd-party services and this data is not saved in the database.

Is there a way to add VBO to my custom table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you cannot add vbo features that don't use the fields api of core drupal. the data from 3rd party services will needed to be imported into a field in order for BVO to work properly.

Comment: You are totally right, actually the better way is to use tableselect form element.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#tableselect

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the hook_entity_info() because:
VBO only supports entity (base or revision) table Implement hook_entity_info() and make your table an entity. Use EntityAPIController so that you don't need to write other boilerplate functions.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1282486

Answer (score 0):

Yes is it possible.We can use contributed data module.This module bind the custom table data and relationship.after that we can integrate by views or create view for that data 
table entity.

Comment: Add some more description